# Bitcoin Core v.26 crashes or closes unexpectely in Ubuntu Linux os

Tags: bitcoin-core

On Ubuntu my bitcoin core v.26 closes every few minutes without saving the downloaded blocks unless I close it first. Maybe a bug but how do I fix this? I updated version 22 to  v.26 because v.22 was not opening anymore at all and crashed totally. So, now I have 31753 blocks left to download and it is taking forever by closing it before it crashes without any warning, so its like a roulette game and very time consuming! Please HELP fix this. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

not totally sure what could be causing this. But I am running a full node on a raspberry pi (1GB ram) and before I editded my `bitcoin.conf` file, I would notice my bitcoin daemon would get randomly disappear. I found some information when I ran `cat /var/log/kern.log` (on rapian OS, not ubuntu)
which I realized I was running out of ram. So after that I tweaked my config file and my OS stopped killing the process.

Can you look for OS logs to see if theres resource management issues going on?

Comment: What do you mean by "tweaked my config"?